# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre Servidor HTTP Apache y Apache Tomcat?

Tags: apache, tomcat

Me gustaría saber cuales son las diferencias fundamentales entre ambas tecnologías.

Comment: en [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30632/difference-between-the-apache-http-server-and-apache-tomcat) en ingles hay una pregunta similar que te podria ayudar

Comment: Alomejor me equivoco, pero tengo entendido que Tomcat sería algo parecido a un "contenedor" de servlets y webapps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache es un servidor web desarrollado por apache , para servir cosas estaticas y mediante extensiones para hostear aplicaciones dinamicas php, phyton, .net y otros.

Tomcat es un servidor web desarrollado por apache tambien, para servir aplicaciones que soporten el JVM aunque tambien soporta aplicaciones estaticas no es su fuerte. y no tiene algunas cosas para escalamiento que si tiene apache pero pueden trabajar juntos para tener esas.

Answer (score 0):

*HTTP Apache* y *Apache Tomcat*, ambas mantenidas y desarrolladas por la *ASF (Apache Software Fundation)*, son software que se ejecuta en un servidor con la finalidad de ayudar a desplegar (*deploy*) un proyecto web. La diferencia radica en el tipo de proyecto que se planea implementar.

*HTTP Apache* es usado para almacenar páginas web estáticas y dinámicas, usando lenguajes como *PHP*, *Perl*, *Python* y *Ruby*.

*Apache Tomcat* también soporta páginas web estáticas (aunque su rendimiento es menor), pero su especialidad son las páginas web dinámicas desarrolladas con la tecnología *Java*, como *Java Servlet*, *JavaServer Page (JSP)*.